# Error: recompile with -fpic when try to install Armadillo

Tags: makefile, installation, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, armadillo

I was trying to install Armadillo in my Ubuntu 14.04.
I run `cmake .` command in the terminal at the folder where the Armadillo files are located and then run `make` command. I got the following errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.a(util.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; 
recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libarmadillo.so.7.800.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: What is wrong with `sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev` to get the properly built binary package from the distribution?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I was trying to install a newer version. SuperLu and armadillo in apt-get is pretty old and the armadillo version doesn't recognize  old superLu version

Comment: Even then you could do _much_ worse than downloading the [sources of the current package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libarmadillo-dev) and building that.  Or even take [the Debian sources](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libarmadillo-dev).

Answer (score 3):

The library at `/usr/local/lib/libsuperlu.a` on your system was most likely not built with `-fPIC` and you are presumably trying to build a shared library that uses code from `libsuperlu.a`. If this is your situation, then the compiler is telling you that the code in `libsuperlu.a` is not relocatable, but your shared library needs it to be. You will need to build your own `libsuperlu.a` and ensure that all of its object files are compiled with the `-fPIC` flag, since the `libsuperlu.a` you currently have installed in `/usr/local/lib` won't work for you.